# How to access(loop through) queryset passed from views to html template inside javascript block in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to loop through array/queryset passed from view to html template in django inside

```
{% block js %}
```

block, is it possible ?

```
{% block js %}
I want to access array/queryset/value passed from views here
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, You can do it Like this,

```
{% for item in array %}
    {‌{ item }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: inside {% block js %}
?

Comment: @SanketPatil Yeah. You can do it anywhere inside the rendering page.

Comment: you mean like this 

{% for i in array %}
<script>
    console.log(i)
</script>
{% endfor %}